# Swift - How to create a date object containing just the time

Tags: swift, date, datetime

I trying to create a date object just containing the time of 1 second past midnight.

I believe the following should work but it just keeps returning **nil**.

```
let dateTime = Date()
        
        let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
        timeFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
        let time = timeFormatter.date(from: "00:00:01")
        print("Time: \(time!)")
```

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `Calendar` do the math, this is more reliable, you aren't using the current date (`dateTime`) anyway.

```
let midnight = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
let oneSecondAfterMidnight = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: 1, to: midnight)
```

This works even if *midnight* doesn't exist due to daylight saving change.

Answer (score 0):

`Date` is not a "date" in any meaningful way. It's a specific point in time, independent of any calendar or location. What you want to express is a point on a calendar: "one second" past an arbitrary calendar point we call "midnight." That's done with DateComponents.

```
var dc = DateComponents()
dc.hour = 0
dc.minute = 0
dc.second = 1
```

This is the second second of the first minute of the first hour (00:00:01) of an arbitrary day on an arbitrary calendar, which is what you've described.

More precisely, it's "zero hours, zero minutes, and one second," which is only "one second after midnight" if you add it to some "midnight." But beyond that, there is no independent "time" type. Those things only have meaning when applied to a Calendar.

(Keep in mind that due to DST change in some parts of world, such as Iran, there are sometimes two midnights in the same day. So when you ask for this kind of thing, you need to be very clear what you mean. Do you want *every* second after midnight or just the first one on a given day?)

Comment: Actually there used to be 2 times 11pm because the first midnight would become 11pm again